# org.eclipse.core.contenttype: Could not create content describer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

I'm working on a custom editor and for that I want to define a custom content-type that can be opened by my editor.

My content-type is a xml with a specific namespace and root element. But everytime I start my Eclipse it fails to create the content-type:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.contenttype 4 0 2018-07-12 12:35:01.911
>   !MESSAGE Could not create content describer for fooeditor.foofile.
>   Content type has been disabled.

My plugin.xml:

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">

 <content-type
       base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
       default-charset="UTF-8"
       describer="org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.XMLRootElementContentDescriber2"
       file-extensions="xml"
       id="foofile"
       name="FOO File"
       priority="high">
         <describer
               class="org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.XMLRootElementContentDescriber2"
               plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.13.0.v20170207-1030">
            <parameter
                  name="element"
                  value="{http://www.foo.com}foo">
            </parameter>
         </describer>
      </content-type>
   </extension>
```

I'm trying to figure this out for the past week and have no idea why this is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use both the `describer` attribute and `<describer` - use one or the other.

Your value for the describer `plugin` is wrong. The plugin id is just `org.eclipse.core.runtime`

So use:

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">

 <content-type
       base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
       default-charset="UTF-8"
       file-extensions="xml"
       id="foofile"
       name="FOO File"
       priority="high">
         <describer
               class="org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.XMLRootElementContentDescriber2"
               plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime">
            <parameter
                  name="element"
                  value="{http://www.foo.com}foo">
            </parameter>
         </describer>
      </content-type>
   </extension>
```